# Identify polarity of 1970's-era dipped tantalum capacitor

Tags: capacitor, polarity, tantalum

Having found the shorted component, now I need to replace it. I'm familiar with dipped tantalum capacitors with painted stripes along one side but these have a dot or stripe up the middle and my Web search didn't help much. I've identified the part as 10uF 25V but I can't figure out which leg should be positive[image]

Comment: I love the aposematic colors on these caps, they just say "hey I'm the problem!" ... Now, the board itself will answer your question, if this was decoupling a power supply, follow the traces, there's probably an IC, a LED, a diode, a 7805, or something around that is has identifiable "+" and "-" pins.

Comment: @bobflux     Learned a new word today !!!   Thx   ap·o·se·mat·ic
/ˌapəseˈmadik/
(of coloration or markings) serving to warn or repel predators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this website: https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/RT001/1uF+35V+Radial+Dipped+Tantalum+Dip+Capacitor+Color+Coded.html

*The polarity is indicated by a dot. Positive lead is the lead on the right when the side with the dot is facing you.*